# Replace every occurrence of the regular expression matching with a particular in VI editor?

Tags: regex, linux, vim, vi, regular-language

suppose I have a text file as follows.

```
create table "kevin".tb1 {
col1,
col2
}
create table "jhone".tb2 {
col1,
col2
}
create table "jake".tb3 {
col1,
col2

}
```

I need to obtain that text file as follows by replacing every table owner name occurrences replace witha same name called "informix".

out put should be like

```
create table "informix".tb1 {
col1,
col2
}
create table "informix".tb2 {
col1,
col2
}
create table "informix".tb3 {
col1,
col2
}
```

in vi editor ,

:%s/"kevin"/"informix"/g

I can replace them individually but I need to do all of them at once.

Comment: what you tried till now ?

Comment: I modified. but I need to use regular expression to filter those words

Comment: `(?<=table ")(.*?)(?=")` try this regex and replace 'informix'

Comment: it is not working

Comment: check here it's for demo https://regex101.com/r/8fsO2Y/2/

Comment: I need a solution which should work on VI editor. this is not working with VI editor

Comment: @CodeManiac The syntax `(?<=table ")` is from Perl/libpcre. In vim it's something like [`\@<=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\@=).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%s/\(create table\) "\i\+"/\1 "informix"/
```

Explanation:

```
% — run through every line in the file
s/ — search and replace
\(create table\) — match the text and store it in the backreference 1
"\i\+" — match any number (more than 1) of identifier characters inside double quotes
\1 "informix" — replace what is found with backreference 1 (text "create table"), a space and text "informix"
```